# Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement OleDbException was unhandeled by user code

Tags: sql, asp.net

My Code:

```
 string MySQL = "INSERT INTO RegisterDatabase (uName, pName, idNumber, age, pass, e-mail) ";
MySQL += "VALUES ('" + Request.Form["username"] + "', '" + Request.Form["fname"] + "', '" + Request.Form["id"] + "', '" + Request.Form["age"] + "', '" + Request.Form["pass"] + "', '" + Request.Form["email"] + "');";
string strConnection = "Provider='Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0';Data Source=" + System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(@"App_Data/RegisterDatabase.accdb");
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection o_con = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(strConnection);
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand o_command = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(MySQL, o_con);
o_con.Open();
o_command.ExecuteNonQuery();
o_con.Close();
```

I'm getting

> Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement" in o_command.ExecuteNonQuery();
>   and that OleDbException was unhandeled by user code.

Here's a picture of mostly everything:
https://i.gyazo.com/d6c30ee3f9988d5d22793540aea98a6c.png

Comment: If ID is numeric you should not use the apostrophes

Comment: Please use parameterized queries! As it is your code has serious vulnerability for [sql injection attacks](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection). Also it would most likely repair your bug, since you don't need the apostrophes.

Comment: You can also try the query in access to see if it works

Comment: is RegisterDatabase table name?

Comment: @levent yeah it's both the table name and the accdb name

Comment: @Cristian I removed the apostrophes from both Request.Form["age"] and Request.Form["id"] (because they are both numeric) and it still gives me the syntax error.

Comment: @Esko ahh... I have not idea what parameterized queries are, I'm doing this for my school project and I just need to get it working, and not worry about vulnerabilities for the moment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem:

When executing the query with Access it gave me the same error, so I removed the '-' in e-mail and it worked.

Be sure you don't use special characters in the field names when working with access.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use parameterized sql, do not use string concatenation of values to create a sql statement with values. One reason why is your code will fail (hard) as soon as someone decides to include an apostrophe `'` in their name. Also you are vulnerable to sql injection attacks should you target a database like Sql Server.
2. Wrap your dipsosable types in `using` blocks to ensure the resources (*db connection in this case*) is closed even in the event of an Exception.
3. Store connection strings in the `web.config` and reference them by name, do not build them up in code unless there is good reason to.
4. Scope Ado.Net instances where you need them and then destroy them (*again, with using block*), this ensures you do not have issues later on contention over a shared connection or a connection that remains open longer than it should.
5. Side note on passwords: never store them as plain text. Ever! Use a secure hashing algorithm like `pbkdf2` (*a good one out of others*) and compare hashes later on.

Now the main issue is `"INSERT INTO RegisterDatabase (uName, pName, idNumber, age, pass, e-mail)`, specically `e-mail`. You need to escape the name using `[]` to enclose it to ensure the `-` character does not cause a syntax problem. The corrected string becomes:

```
INSERT INTO RegisterDatabase (uName, pName, idNumber, age, pass, [e-mail])
```

---

Here is your code with those changes. I guessed on the types for id and age and passed them as those types. Refine this further as you see fit.

```
string strConnection = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["yourConnectionName"].ConnectionString;
using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(strConnection))
using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand())
{
    cmd.Connection = con;
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO RegisterDatabase (uName, pName, idNumber, age, pass, [e-mail]) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?)";

    cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@uName", OleDbType.VarChar)).Value = Request.Form["username"];
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@pName", OleDbType.VarChar)).Value = Request.Form["fname"];
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@idNumber", OleDbType.Int)).Value = int.Parse(Request.Form["id"]);
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@age", OleDbType.Int)).Value = int.Parse(Request.Form["age"]);
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@pass", OleDbType.VarChar)).Value = Request.Form["pass"];
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@email", OleDbType.VarChar)).Value = Request.Form["email"];

    con.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```